# Как считывать слова из файла на С++?

Tags: windows, c++

В файле находятся ФИО в виде: Имя Фамилия Отчество. Как считать Имя, Фамилию и Отчество в отдельные ячейки? Чтобы потом можно было их использовать?

Приложение - Win32 Console Application.

Answer (score 5):

Можешь записать фамилию имя и отчество, всё с новой строки и читать

```
std::ifstream file("fio.txt"); 
std::string surname, name, patronymic;
std::getline(file, surname);
std::getline(file, name);
std::getline(file, patronymic);
```

а если всё в одной строке, то третий параметр это разделитель

```
std::ifstream file("fio.txt"); 
std::string surname, name, patronymic;
std::getline(file, surname, ' ');
std::getline(file, name, ' ');
std::getline(file, patronymic, ' ');
```

Comment: Ух, ты! Супер! Как-то проглядел третий параметр у getline :-o

Comment: Возьму на заметку) Еще учу с++)

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать **С-like style**:

1. считываем по строчке
2. разбиваем strtok() на слова

Возможно удастся за одно действие использовать что-то в духе sscanf("%s %s %s", buf1, buf2, buf3).

Если использовать **C++-like style**:

1. Используем ifstream для считывания из файла
2. Считываем каждую строчку в string
3. Разбираем string с помощью [boost::tonenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm), иначе получите a lot of pain (много боли).

PS: конечно, можно сделать по-другому: смешать вызовы C++ и C-функций или вручную искать пробелы и их удалять из считанных строчек, но это явно не метод джедая. Иначе зачем, спрашивается, нужно использовать такой мощный язык как с++?

Answer (score 1):

Простым fscanf(); он принимает все переменные через разделители в виде: пробел, таб, смещение курсора(ака n) и много пробелов. Достаточно просто 3 раза подряд считать переменную типа строка (%s).